# Android 11 Multiple Images with limit

Tags: android, image, android-10.0, android-11

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, Image_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I use this to select multiple images but not getting any limit option.

Comment: Android does not provide a way to set limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
if (clipData != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
        String path = getRealPathFromURI(item.getUri());
        if (path != null) {
            File imageFile = new File(path);
            imageList.add(new File(imageFile.toString()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Invalid Path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    if (path != null) {
        File imageFile = new File(uri);
        imageList.add(imageFile);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Invalid Path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//if Images limit is 5
if (imageList.size() > 5) {
    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Max 5 photos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for (int i = imageList.size() - 1; i >= 5; i--) {
        imageList.remove(i);
    }
    
}
```

I used this onActivityResult() method. it deletes extra photos

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).